# how to solve the many error in vscide: Cmake/share/Modules/CmakeDetermine.cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, clang++

I'm stumped.

1.Install in vscode: Codelldb+clangd+cmake+cmake_tools+c/cpp.

2.Installed msys2(64). Updated packages.

3.Did everything according to the instructions.

4.

```
cmake-tools-kits.json
     [
          {
            "name": "Clang 13.0.0 x86_64-w64-windows-gnu",
            "compilers": {
              "C": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang.exe",
              "CXX": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang++.exe"
            },
            "preferredGenerator": {
              "name":"MSyS Makefiles"
          },
          "environmentVariables": {
            "CMT_MINGW_PATH": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\"
          }
          }
        ]
```

4.b)

```
cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**",
                            "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
    }
```

4.c)

```
launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to understand related properties.
    // Hover to view the description of an existing property.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "LLDB: Generate and debug order files",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\debug",
        "args": [],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "preLaunchTask": "Clang++: Compile single file"
      }
```

4.d)

```
settings.json
{
    "clangd.path": "c:\\Users\\Win10Pro\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd\\install\\13.0.0\\clangd_13.0.0\\bin\\clangd.exe",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "--log=verbose"
  ],
      "clangd.checkUpdates": true,
      "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,  
    "cmake.cmakePath": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\cmake.exe",
    "cmake.mingwSearchDirs": [
      "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin"
   ],
   "cmake.generator": "MSyS Makefiles",
  "cmake.configureOnEdit": false,
  "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
  "cmake.copyCompileCommands": "",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"}
```

4.e)

```
tasks.json
{
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Clang++: Compile single file",
        // Compiler path
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
        "args": [
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.cpp",
          "-o",
          "debug.exe",
          "-g",
          "-Wall",
          "-Wextra",
          "-pthread",
          "-fuse-ld=lld",
          "-fstandalone-debug",
          "-fcolor-diagnostics",
          "-fparse-all-comments",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-std=c++20",
          "--target=x86_64-w64-mingw"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
          "echo": true,
          "reveal": "always", 
          "focus": false, 
          "panel": "shared" 
        },
        "detail": "Clang++: Compile a single file"
      }
```

5

```
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Ex VERSION 0.1.0)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
    ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules
    )
include(MSyS Makefiles)
add_executable(Ex main.cpp)
```

6. MSyS Makefiles.cmake
   set(CMake_Make_Program "C:/msys64/clang64/bin/mingw32-make.exe")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
   "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
   -g
   -pthread
   -fuse-ld=lld
   -fstandalone-debug
   -Wall
   -Wextra
   -fcolor-diagnostics
   -fparse-all-comments
   -stdlib=libc++
   -std=c++20
   --target=x86_64-w64-mingw"
   )
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

ERROR : `CMake Error at C:/msys64/clang64/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1075 (file):file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory)`All error in `C:/msys64/clang64/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeDetermine`

I really don't understand. Maybe inside msys2 cmake doesn't work? Maybe use mingw64 instead of clang64 both in terms of environment and clang++ compilation? Just searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer. And I had to ask a question here because I really don't understand what my mistake is?

Comment: As I see it, the general idea of using VS Code is that you want a specific environment, and have it set up just the way you like it. Possibly because you need to be portable to some other OS. If you only want to write C++ code for Windows, without any strong preferences, you could just install Visual Studio 2022 (without "Code" in the name). It just works(TM).

Comment: I see. It's just that I did everything as instructed [here](https://programmer.help/blogs/vscode-configuration-c-c-vscode-clang-clangd-lldb-cmake-git.html), with my additions, since it didn't work as instructed. Maybe really use mingw64 instead of clang64 and see what happens?

Comment: That you need that kind of instruction is just the problem. With Visual Studio (without Code) you run the installer, check the boxes for the features you want (like C++) and click Install. Done. You can then still later modify the configuration and add plugins, but you don't have to _start_ with that - it just works out of the box, by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. and happy holidays.